# Flutter - aad_b2c_webview error on scopes

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, azure-ad-b2c

I'm developing a Flutter App and I've implemented the login using the library aad_b2c_webview and a webpage.
I have a different behaviour between iOS and Android.
On Android, using version 0.0.51 everything works fine, but once I try to use a newer version I get this error:

> Response ({"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADB2C90117: The scope 'openid%20offline_access%20profile%20https://myWebSite.onmicrosoft.com/exm.be.webapi/access_as_user' provided in the request is not supported.\r\nCorrelation ID: 53dc1c3f-a814-428c-8adf-a3153d5eb8b3\r\nTimestamp: 2024-03-07 13:24:06Z\r\n"})

On iOS I seem to get the error while using an earlier version.
Everything works fine using version later than 0.0.53.

Reading the changelog on its page https://pub.dev/packages/aad_b2c_webview/changelog it doesn't seem to have nothing new outside of new functions and fixes.

My implementation of the webview is

```
return ADB2CEmbedWebView(
      loadingReplacement: const Loading(),
      optionalParameters: const [],
      tenantBaseUrl: aadB2CUserAuthFlow,
      userFlowName: aadB2CUserFlowName,
      clientId: aadB2CClientID,
      redirectUrl: aadB2CRedirectURL,
      onRedirect: (context) => Loading.modalLoading(),
      scopes: aadB2CScopes,
      onAnyTokenRetrieved: (Token anyToken) {
        ...
      },
      onIDToken: (Token token) {
        ...
      },
      onAccessToken: (Token token) {
        ...
      },
      onRefreshToken: (Token token) {
        ...
      },
    );
```

I've tried all the version on both devices and Android stop working after 0.0.51, iOS on the other hand starts working after 0.0.53
What am I missing?